# How to obtain marginal density [x], given [y|x] and [y]

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, conditioning

I came across a problem knowing density of Y, conditional density of Y given X, how would I obtain density of X? Or would this even unique?

Comment: One counterexample to unicity is if $f(y  \mid x)$ do not depend on $x$, then it  is equal to $f(y)$ so **any** $f(x)$ works!  There must be more interesting counterexamples!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen That pretty well captures the issue.  If the conditional density of $Y$ is the same for $n$ values of $X,$ then once you have a found one solution, you can repartition the probability of $X$ *in any way you please* among those $n$ values without changing any of the conditions of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no unique solution, unless there is some extra conditions. One counterexample will do, and the discrete case is simpler than the case with densities.

Let there be four urns, with the composition 1 red/4 black, 2 red/3 black, 3 red/ 2 black and 4 red/1 black ball. $f(y \mid x)$ is the probability of drawing red from urn $x$, urn probabilities are $f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)$ non-negative and summing to 1. Using the law of total probability we find the equations
$$ 5 f(\text{red}) = f(\text{red}\mid 1) f(1) + f(\text{red}\mid 2) f(2) + f(\text{red}\mid 3) f(3) + f(\text{red}\mid 4) f(4) \\
f(1)+f(2)+f(3)+f(4) = 1 $$ and there are obviously many solutions to this underdetermined system.

One interesting interpretation of this question is bayesian: If we know the likelihood and the posterior, do this determine the prior? The answer, in general, is no.

Comment: Thanks for your explicit example and Bayesian implication. @kjetilbhalvorsen

Comment: If you think kjetil's post answered your query, please upvote and accept it by clicking on the tick symbol alongside the post.